# update sqlite database only if the values is not null android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an activity which updates person info

i want to know if there is a way to update only the non null values and the rest you leave it the same here is my update function

```
  public boolean modifierMember (String nom ,String prenom ,String tel,String profile ,String etat,int id ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,nom);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,prenom);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,tel);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,profile);

    contentValues.put(COL_k, etat);

    db.update(TABLE_Membre,contentValues,"IDM=?",new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below updated method for your requirement,

```
      public boolean modifierMember (String nom ,String prenom ,String tel,String profile ,String etat,int id ){
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
           ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

           if(nom != null)
                  contentValues.put(COL_2,nom);

           if(prenom != null)    
                  contentValues.put(COL_3,prenom);

           if(tel != null)
                   contentValues.put(COL_4,tel);

           if(profile != null)
                   contentValues.put(COL_5,profile);

           if(etat != null)
                    contentValues.put(COL_k, etat);

           db.update(TABLE_Membre,contentValues,"IDM=?",new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
          return true;

      }
```

Comment: thank you so much very nice of you to write all of it

Comment: but when i do does the db.update know where to put every content values without me specifying where eacch one goes ???

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that, one way to do this would be to check whether the value is **null** or what for a particular `column`, in your case it can go like :

```
if(nom != null) {
    contentValues.put(COL_2,nom);
}
// Same for other fields.
```

in the above you can check for other values similarly and if they are **not null** then only add to the `contentValues`

**Edit**

It also depends upon what are passing in your `modifierMember()` function as argument

for e.g if you pass 'null' then you need to compare as i said above, if you pass `""` then you have to compare accordingly, this solely depends upon what you pass as the argument

Comment: im gettin the info from a text feild that a user fills so if he leaves it empty so its null right